# Unable to setup input stream: unable to set IO streams as raw terminal: The handle is invalid

Tags: git, githooks, git-husky

I am trying to use 'husky' to implement git hooks. I installed husky as a dev-dependancy and included a command in the scripts object. When I try to run the command '**git commit**' I receive the following error:

```
 $git commit -m "first commit"
unable to setup input stream: unable to set IO streams as raw terminal: The 
handle is invalid.
```

My package.json file is as follows:

```
    {
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "precommit":"npm run test"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "husky": "~1.0.0-rc.15"
  }
}
```

My expectation is to run the test command but I get an error.

Please help!

Thanks in advance